# how to create a news aggregator?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, aggregation

Planning to start a small aggregator for a personal project, so far I have a few inquiries on gathering information for the site. I'm still clueless on where to begin. what kind of infrastructure do i need? where do i get the feeds and can I sort them out depending on the theme of the info requested?

any feedback is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty open-ended question, but here's where I'd start:

- Technology for handling feeds -- [WCF Syndication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412202.aspx).  Also, read and understand the [RSS](http://cyber.law.harvard.edu/rss/rss.html) and [Atom](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4287) specs.
- Infrastructure -- depends on your situation.  Is it just for you, or a few friends or are you talking about building the next Google Reader?  If it's smaller-scale, then look at a hosting solutions like GoDaddy, DiscountASP.NET, etc.  (There's hundreds of them.)  If you're talking a larger-scale type of solution, look at hosting it in the cloud - Rackspace, Amazon, Windows Azure.
- Where do you get feeds?  Pretty much anywhere.  Personally, if this site is for other users, let the users enter them in (why be in the business of trying to guess what feeds people would want to subscribe to?).

I think you need to provide more requirements in order to get more solid feedback.  Start with looking at WCF Syndication and get a feel for that library in terms of how to programmatically handle RSS and ATOM feeds (both subscribing and publishing).  Once you understand that, I think you'll have a better handle on your next steps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks D Hoerster, let's wait for the others to reply. But you did give an excellent answer.

Comment: well, i want to create an aggregator product that is specific to a country. can I sort out RSS feeds by the tag of the country? thanks!

Comment: Depends on how the feeds are built.  I'm assuming you're not building the feeds, you're getting them from somewhere -- CNN.com, news.google.com, etc.  The RSS spec has a `language` element that defaults to `en-us`.  However, it's an optional element.  Atom also has a language attribute, and it's also optional.  So, and that's the problem with feeds, is that you may not always get good information.